# Trying to build a model inside with dplyr::do then pull coef(model) in the same dplyr::do call

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to build a series of linear models for a set of Standard Curves.

Currently this code is working to produce my desired outputs (Intercept and Slope of each Linear Model):

```
slopes <- STANDARDS %>% group_by(plate, col, row, conc_ug_mL) %>% do(
    #model = lm(value ~ variable, data = .),
    intercept = coef(lm(value ~ variable, data = .))[1],
    slope = coef(lm(value ~ variable, data = .))[2])
```

But I had to comment the model line out and call lm twice. I would really like to make it like this:

```
slopes2 <- STANDARDS %>% group_by(plate, col, row, conc_ug_mL) %>% do(
    model = lm(value ~ variable, data = .),
    intercept = coef(.$model)[1],
    slope = coef(.$model)[2])
```

The second block of code does not raise an error but return NULL for both Intercept and Slope. I think my problem is not understanding the reference structure within dplyr::do.

But am just learning dplyr and not sure of how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is not reproducible, please see [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2572423) for more information. In addition, this [blog post](http://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/) and the [broom](https://github.com/dgrtwo/broom) package may prove helpful.

Comment: the package [broom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) might be useful here.

Comment: Thanks @JasonAizkalns. I will make sure my future posts comply with the community's reproducibility guide lines. I appreciate the broom package recommendation, I will start using that to helpfully format my dplyr outputs!

Comment: Thank you for the broom recommendation too! @beetroot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't need the `.$model`.  Using a reproducible example

```
 data(mtcars)
 mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>% 
   do({model = lm(wt~gear, data=.)
   data.frame(intercept= coef(model)[1], slope=coef(model)[2])})
 #    cyl intercept      slope
 # (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)
 #1     4  3.829406 -0.3773438
 #2     6  4.180750 -0.2757500
 #3     8  5.205208 -0.3670417
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, and apologies for not making my example reproducible. Could you explain the significance of the ' { ' ? When I tried replacing the ' { '  with ' ( ' an error was returned. Is ' {  ' just defining a unnamed function?

Comment: @NathanDay It is to separate multiple lines.